# Savon—configure to use TLS 1.2

Tags: soap, savon

I'm working on an old project using Savon to connect to the SalesForce api. I'm getting this error:

```
UNSUPPORTED_CLIENT: TLS 1.0 has been disabled in this organization. Please use TLS 1.1 or higher when connecting to Salesforce using https
```

How do I get it to use TLS 1.2? Or is there a simple alternative to Savon that does use TLS 1.2?

Comment: Hi @mirror318, Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @ecoologic I did solve it, but I can't remember how, sorry! I think I just updated all the related gems, and when creating the savon client I set `ssl_version: :TLSv1_2`

Comment: I second this, :TLSv1_2 also saved me when forced to upgrade from v1.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Savon uses HTTPI as a common interface for Ruby's HTTP libraries

Configure Savon to use a specific library with:

```
HTTPI.adapter = :httpclient
HTTPI.adapter = :curb
...
```

it currently tries the libs in the following order:

```
[:httpclient, :curb, :em_http, :excon, :net_http, :net_http_persistent]
```

If you haven't installed `httpclient`, it will try `curb`next and so on.

You should try setting an explicit lib and see if it works for you.

Comment: I tried updating the excon gem and specifically setting it, but same error

Answer (score 0):

Just to help others in the future who may face the same problem. It seems the TLS level is not built in the savon gem but in the httpi adapter. By changing the adapter to httpclient (installed the gem, put require 'httpclient') the savon gem starts using it without further configuration. Just remove the ssl_level params and the latest and more modern cypher is used. Problem solved.