# Rails (with Savon): How to make TLS request (and not SSLv3)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssl, tls1.2, savon

I have a Rails (5.1.3) app that uses Savon (2.11.0) for communicating with a 3rd party service. This service requested me recently that in order to use it, I need to make all my requests with TLS 1.2.

How do I do that - do I have to set up something globally in my Rails app or only to pass some parameters to the Savon call?

I tried doing it this way:

```
Savon.client(wsdl: url, ssl_version: :TLSv1) # or using :TLSv1_2
```

(found it [here](http://savonrb.com/version2/globals.html))
but this doesn't seem to work.

What's the best practice to set TLS to be used for a Rails 5 app?

Comment: Try setting `HTTPI.adapter = :net_http` and trying again with `:TLSv1_2`. [Savon relies on HTTPI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46881832/3784008) to interface with lower-level HTTP clients, and it's possible the default client you're using does not support TLS 1.2.